# Alocação em C - object was probably modified after being freed

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados

Estou fazendo um programa de estrutura de dados e estou obtendo o seguinte erro:

> arq(1966,0x7fff7970f300) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fc058404c38:
>   incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified
>   after being freed.
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Mas não estou fazendo nenhum free. A situação é a seguinte: estou trabalhando com uma arvore AVL, a primeira vez que tento inserir um elemento na arvore, funciona tranquilamente.

Agora, se eu tentar fazer a inserção de outro elemento, seja na mesma árvore ou em outra, seja o mesmo registro ou o mesmo, aponta esse erro, sempre nesses endereços, procurei várias coisas mas não achei o erro.

Gostaria de saber onde está o erro, pois não consigo imaginar o que procurar nas funções, visto que na primeira vez ele funciona normalmente mas na segunda vez ele aponta esse erro.

Parte do código:

```
 NODO *D;
  REG * R;
  int ok;

  inicializar(&D);
  R = criar_registro("GUT-2020","MCBA123","Carro","Azul",3,"Jose Joaquim", "1234","3214543");
  inserir(&D, "GUT-2020", *R, &ok);
  printf("Impressao: \n\n");
  exibir(D);
  //ate aqui tudo certo

  REG * R2;
  NODO * D2;
  int ok2;
  inicializar(&D2);
  R2 = criar_registro("GUT-2021","MCBA123","Carro","Azul",3,"Jose Joaquim", "1234","3214543");
  inserir(&D2, "GUT-2021", *R2, &ok2); //erro
```

funções envolvidas no problema:

```
void inicializar(NODO **Dic)
{
    *Dic = NULL;
}

REG * criar_registro(char placa[], char chassi[], char marca[], char modelo[], char portas, char proprietario[], char cpf[], char telefone[])
{
  REG * registro = (REG*)malloc(sizeof(REG));
  strcpy(registro->chave,placa);
  strcpy(registro->carro.placa,placa);
  strcpy(registro->carro.chassi,chassi);
  strcpy(registro->carro.marca,marca);
  strcpy(registro->carro.modelo,modelo);
  registro->carro.portas = portas;
  strcpy(registro->carro.proprietario,proprietario);
  strcpy(registro->carro.cpf,cpf);
  strcpy(registro->carro.telefone,telefone);

  return registro;
}
```

e a parte que é executada na função inserir é a seguinte:
O erro acontece na segunda vez que vou executar ela, para uma variavel apontando para NULL (igual acontece na primeira vez que executo ela, mas nessa primeira vez funciona tudo corretamente)

```
  NODO * A

  if (*Dic == NULL)
    {                 //{INSERÇÃO}
      A = (NODO*) malloc(sizeof(Dic));
      if (A == NULL)
    return 0;
      A->esq = NULL;
      A->dir = NULL;
      strcpy(A->reg.chave, chave);
      A->reg.carro = reg.carro;
      A->FB = 0;
      *OK = 1;
      *Dic = A;
      return 1;
    }
```

Comment: O problema pode estar nas funções. Poste o código delas, se possível.

Comment: postei o código das funções que são executadas!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu tenho a forte impressão de que o problema é o `sizeof(Dic)` na alocação do seu último código. Ele vai retornar o tamanho do ponteiro na variável `Dic` e não o tamanho da estrutura (como intencionado). Assim, as suas manipulações da variável (cópias de dados) vão invadir áreas de memória que você não alocou de fato.

Use `sizeof(NODO)` no lugar, que deve resolver.

P.S.: Você não compartilhou o código das estruturas na pergunta, mas analisando bem rapidamente parece que o seu código tem muito potencial para invasão de memória (nas cópias das strings) e para vazamentos de memória (na criação dos registros, já que a sua função inserir aparentemente copia os dados para uma estrutura interna, desconsiderando o ponteiro para o registro que vc já tinha alocado). Eu sugiro dar uma boa revisada no código (se possível usando `strncpy` para copiar strings, e avaliando o uso de memória do processo em alguns testes de carga). :)

Comment: Era isso mesmo o problema, foi uma distração, não acredito que perdi tanto tempo por isso hahaha - mas obrigado pela ajuda e vou dar uma revisada no código sim, vou levar essa dica em consideração!