# Como ver o quanto de memória ocupa tal variável no C++? E como se utiliza o define?

Tags: c++, variáveis, memória

Como ver o quanto de memória ocupa tal variável do tipo `int, char e long` no C++?

E como se utiliza o `#define`?

Comment: Acho que você está misturando dois assuntos completamente distintos em um único tópico. Não acha que convém você criar duas perguntar diferentes?

Comment: Concordo com o @Math, o ideal é fazer perguntas separadas. Eu respondi sobre o `define` até porque a melhor resposta é p/ não usá-lo em C++ mas cada assunto deveria ser em uma pergunta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O `#define` não deve ser usado em C++ (na verdade nem mesmo em C moderno), use uma constante com a palavra chave [`const`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/const-cpp?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=vs-2019). De qualquer forma mostrei um exemplo de `#define`.

Fiz um exemplo nos padrões do C++ mostrando o tamanho das variáveis conforme você pediu. Note que o `sizeof` é um operador, ele sequer precisa dos parênteses em algumas situações. Este operador pega o tamanho do dado usado como operando, no caso a variável, no momento da compilação, portanto ele não tem custo algum em tempo de execução.

Em geral em C++ não se usa bibliotecas legadas do C.

```
#include <iostream>
#define tamanho 10
const int elementos = 10;
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a = 1;
    char b = 'a';
    float c = 1.0f;
    double d = 2.0d;
    short e = 1000;
    long f = 100000;
    int *g = new int[tamanho];
    int h[elementos];
    cout << "a tem " << sizeof(a) << " bytes\n";
    cout << "b tem " << sizeof(b) << " bytes\n";
    cout << "c tem " << sizeof(c) << " bytes\n";
    cout << "d tem " << sizeof(d) << " bytes\n";
    cout << "e tem " << sizeof(e) << " bytes\n";
    cout << "f tem " << sizeof(f) << " bytes\n";
    cout << "g tem " << sizeof(g) << " bytes\n";
    cout << "h tem " << sizeof(h) << " bytes\n";
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/llwgBb). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/VariableSize). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Memory/VariableSize.cpp).

Note que alocar dados dinamicamente pode trazer problemas para determinar o tamanho da alocação. Você teria que ter outros meios de descobrir o tamanho alocado. Mas note também que neste caso o tamanho da variável realmente é o tamanho do ponteiro. O resultado não está errado. A variável em si só ocupa 4 *bytes* em arquiteturas 32 bits. O que o ponteiro aponta é que vai ter um outro tamanho extra, mostra na variável `h` (alocação estática) que não foi alocado com um ponteiro como foi em `g` (alocação dinâmica).

Saiba mais sobre a diferença da [alocação na *stack* e no *heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101).

Comment: Aqui tem um bom exemplo do que pode ocorrer por essas confusões de uso de `sizeof` com resultado diferente do esperado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48055/aloca%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-c-object-was-probably-modified-after-being-freed/48107

Comment: @AugustoVasques resolvido, uma das coisas que não gosto de C/C++ é que os compiladores praticamente criam linguagens diferentes e cada um usa flags diferentes em momentos diferentes, e lá não tenho controle disso.

Answer (score 1):

Podes descobrir quantos bytes certa variável ocupa através da função `sizeof()`.

Essa função recebe uma variável como argumento, ou as palavras reservadas que representam as variáveis: char, int, float etc.

**Exemplo:**

```
printf("Char: %d bytes\n", sizeof(char));
printf("Int: %d bytes\n", sizeof(int));
printf("Float: %d bytes\n", sizeof(float));
printf("Double: %d bytes\n", sizeof(double));
```

Não se esqueça de incluir a biblioteca `stdio.h`

> [Fonte](http://www.cprogressivo.net/2013/03/A-funcao-sizeof-e-blocos-vizinhos-de-memoria-em-C.html)

Para usar o define é bem simples:

```
#define CONTADOR 0
```

Então, basta usar o nome do `define` no código.

**Exemplo:**

```
#define CONTADOR 10
int main() {
  int vetor[CONTADOR]; //Vetor com CONTADOR posições
}
```

Comment: `sizeof` não é uma função, é um operador resolvido em tempo de compilação.

Answer (score 1):

o define funciona assim:

```
#define TAMMAX 100
```

primeiro vem o define depois o nome e o que contém nesse nome, 
quando e feito a compilação tudo que esta com o nome `TAMMAX` no seu codigo e substituido por 100, por exemplo:

```
int vetor[TAMMAX] // vetor de 100 indices
```