# O que ocorre com o espaço na memória após o uso de variável local?

Tags: variáveis, memória

No termino da execução de uma função suas variáveis locais são "destruídas", correto? Os espaços na memória possuem valores quaisquer, em C podemos notar ao mandar imprimir uma variável que não inicializamos, será mostrado um valor que não foi atribuído pelo programador, pois o mesmo já estava alocado naquele espaço.

Se ao declararmos uma variável que por acaso foi atribuído a ela o espaço que pertencia à variável local "destruída" e não inicializarmos a mesma com nenhum valor, ao mandarmos imprimir essa variável o valor que irá apresentar será o valor da variável local que foi "destruída"?

Quando falo em "destruir" a variável local estou me referindo a liberar o espaço na memória onde ela residia e apagar o conteúdo, ou somente liberar o espaço deixando o conteúdo a ser sobreposto por outro que por ventura venha a utilizar aquele espaço.

Comment: Não ocorre "destruição", o espaço de memória simplesmente se torna disponível para novas alocações. Se ocorrer uma nova alocação e não for atribuído um valor inicial será utilizado o lixo de memória existente.

Comment: O lixo seŕa o conteudo da variavel que ocupava aquele local da memoria?

Comment: O que existia gravado na posição de memória alocada que pode não coincidir com a alocação de uma variável anteriormente alocada naquela região.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Obviamente depende da linguagem e até da implementação dela se a [especificação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111284/101) da linguagem deixar isso livro. Em geral variáveis locais são alocadas no [*stack*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101) e ao final do escopo de uso dela (pode não ser a função, pode ser um escopo menor) o espaço fica livre para uso por outras variáveis, em geral uma nova chamada a uma função. Não há um apagamento do valor ali, até onde sei em nenhuma tecnologia a não ser que de alguma forma um objeto seja criado pensando nisso.

Algumas linguagens podem usar o *heap* até para variáveis locais, ou mesmo outro mecanismo. Geralmente neste caso precisa ter um mecanismo de liberação automática da variável porque a variável não deveria segurar um objeto mais que o seu [tempo de vida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101). Novamente liberação não significa apagar o dado.

Note que uma [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) não costuma ser destruída porque este é um conceito do seu código, as variáveis não existem em tempo de execução, existem [objetos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205482/101) que estão em posições de memória que no seu código você referenciou através de um identificador que chamamos de variável.

Em C o comportamento é realmente uma variável declarada e não inicializada pegar o valor que estava lá, não necessariamente de uma variável anterior, simplesmente o valor existente será usado toda vez que referenciar a variável sem uma nova atribuição explícita. Fora C++ praticamente nenhuma outra linguagem age assim, em geral a especificação determina que o valor mesmo não inicializado explicitamente tenha seu valor zerado pelo compilador. Ou pode proibir um código compilar se não houver a inicialização explícita. C é considerado o Assembly portável e não tem esse tipo de preocupação.

Pode ver mais sobre consumo de memória das variáveis em [Como ver o quanto de memória ocupa tal variável no C++? E como se utiliza o define?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52142/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: *"Em C o comportamento é realmente uma variável declarada e não inicializada pegar o valor que estava lá"*, isso me fez lembrar um teste ainda na faculdade, e isso realmente acontecia, achei bizarro na época :)